# Ubuntu Software Center not working; says the package catalog needs repair

Tags: 11.10, software-center

When I want to install anything in Ubuntu Software Center I get [this message](http://www.dodaj.rs/?2N/Zy/2SiP2mRM/screenshot-at-2011-10-07.png) :

[image: software center error]

Comment: What happens when you try clicking the Repair button?

Comment: When I click on repair and enter the password, the process starts and stops. Software Center is up again but the problem remains the same.

Comment: sudo update
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/sudoers: too many levels of includes near line 25 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/sudoers near line 25
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting

Comment: sorry, forgot apt-get, try this `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Sorry. What is the name for copy service messages?

Comment: The output is too long. Where to copy it and leave you a link?

Comment: maybe on http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Here's the text. http://pastebin.com/qSQsyUap

Comment: When I try to install over synaptic package manager, I get this message http://pastebin.com/q5D5zae4

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
sudo apt-get update
```

to update your package list.
Then

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

to clean up any partial packages.
Then

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

to clean up the apt cache.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

will clean up any unneeded dependencies.
If while doing this you can identify the broken package this code will very forcefully remove it.

```
sudo dpkg --remove -force --force-remove-reinstreq package name
```

Change package name to the real name of course.