# Ubuntu Software Center not working

Tags: package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu Software Center not working; says the package catalog needs repair](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64718/ubuntu-software-center-not-working-says-the-package-catalog-needs-repair)

It says the package catalog needs repair.
I tried with this command "sudo apt-get install -f"
But it says unable to correct dependencies.
Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Try running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` from a Terminal.

Comment: I tried it, but it not support.

Comment: What does it say when you run that command? Please paste the full output on Pastebin.

Comment: go to synaptic package manager and remove broken packages........

Comment: Open up Synaptic -> Edit -> Fix broken packages.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, this is what fixed it for me:

- *Open your terminal and write these lines:*

  ```
  sudo ldconfig

  sudo apt-get check

  sudo apt-get update
  ```

  *(Till this moment it kept giving me the same error)*

  ```
  sudo apt-get -f upgrade --fix-missing
  ```

  *(And after this ^ line, the problem was solved)*

Comment: go to synaptic package manager and remove broken packages........